# Tomcat won't deploy war because of error nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/SynchronizationType;

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa-2.1, tomcat8.5

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application (bundled as war) in tomcat. While starting up the tomcat, it throws error

```
Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType
```

I know this could be either because of method is not found at runtime or tomcat is loading some other jar which does not have this method.
I checked from where tomcat is trying to load this module and it loaded from correct jar file.

```
[Loaded javax.persistence.SynchronizationType from file:/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-8.5.33/webapps/myapp%23%23003/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar]
```

I am not sure why am i still getting this error.

**UPDATE**

Followings are my dependency related to JPA and hibernate

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: show us all jpa / hibernate related dependencies in your pom

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I have added the dependencies as an update.

Comment: What is the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency version?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki It's `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE`.